# webview Url: Load Resource from Windows-DLL

Tags: javascript, winapi, webview

With TWebBrowser (IExplorer) content can be loaded from a DLL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res://.\MyPackWeb.dll/JSCRIPT/JQUERY"></script>
```

How do you do this with Edge/Chrome **window.chrome.webview**?

I'm working with Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image data is not inserted into the HTML page as a link, but as a data stream in the form of a Base64 string.

```
<img 
src="data:image/png;base64,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"> </img>
```

The data can be transmitted via a "window.chrome.webview.addEventListener".
[Json-Array to Html-table via window.chrome.webview.addEventListener, Server Delphi-Appplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032879/json-array-to-html-table-via-window-chrome-webview-addeventlistener-server-delp)