# Json-Array to Html-table via window.chrome.webview.addEventListener, Server Delphi-Appplication

Tags: javascript, json, delphi, webview

I am passing Json data to the embedded Edge browser from my Delphi application. Javascript reports a parser error.

[image]

[image]

If I change the value for `Sender.DefaultInterface.PostWebMessageAsJson(PChar(LcTxt));` in Delphi, no message arrives in the browser `alert('Ich bin drin!')`. **How can this Gordian knot be untied?**

Code Delphi:

```
unit UMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, 
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, WebView2, Winapi.ActiveX, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Edge, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Panel1: TPanel;
  Web: TEdgeBrowser;
  Button1: TButton;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure WebWebMessageReceived(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser;
    Args: TWebMessageReceivedEventArgs);
private
  { Private-Deklarationen }
public
  { Public-Deklarationen }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
   system.JSON;

   {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
//WebView2Loader.dll muss existieren!
var
  LcFile: string;
begin
  //web.Navigate('https://www.embarcadero.com');
  LcFile := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'WebView2Loader.dll';
  if not FileExists(LcFile) then
    raise Exception.Create('WebView2Loader.dll not exists!');

  LcFile := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'jsontab.html';
  web.Navigate(LcFile);
end;

procedure TForm1.WebWebMessageReceived(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser; Args: 
    TWebMessageReceivedEventArgs);
var
  LoJsArr: TJSONArray;
  Lch    : Char;
  LcTxt  : string;
begin
  LoJsArr := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    Lch := 'A';
    for LcTxt in ['rot', 'gruen', 'Blau'] do //grün
    begin
      // a)
      //   LoJsArr.Add(LcTxt);
      // b)
      //   LoJsArr.Add(TJSONObject.Create(TJSONPair.Create(Lch, LcTxt)));
      // c)
           LoJsArr.Add(TJSONObject.Create(TJSONPair.Create('name', LcTxt)));
      Lch := succ(Lch);
    end;
    // a) LoJsArr.ToJSON === '["rot","gr\u00FCn","Blau"]'
    // b) LoJsArr.ToJSON === '[{"A":"rot"},{"B":"gr\u00FCn"},{"C":"Blau"}]'
    // c) LoJsArr.ToJSON === '[{"name":"rot"},{"name":"gr\u00FCn"},{"name":"Blau"}]'

    LcTxt := LoJsArr.ToJSON;

    Sender.DefaultInterface.PostWebMessageAsJson(PChar(LcTxt));
  finally
    LoJsArr.Free;
  end;
 end;
end.
```

Code HTML (jsontab.html) [Code-Transfer new XMLHttpRequest()](https://w3.p2hp.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_table_dynamic):

```
 <blink>
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
 <head>
 <script>
    window.chrome.webview.addEventListener('message', arg => 
    {
      alert('Ich bin drin!');
      let step = 1;
      let text = '';
      try 
      {
        const myObj = JSON.parse(arg.data);
        step = 2;
        text = "<table border='1'>"
        for (let x in myObj) {
           text += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
        }
        step = 3;
        text += "</table>"    
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        step =  'Fehler: ' + e.message;
      }
      alert('step: ' + step);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;       
    });

    function XClick(id) 
    {
      /* Serveranfrage xmlhttp.send("..");  */
      window.chrome.webview.postMessage(id);
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h2>Make a table based on JSON data.</h2>
     <input id="btn" type="button" value="Request" onclick="XClick(this.id);" />
     <p id="demo"></p>
 </body>
 </html>
 </blink>
```

Comment: Add `arg.data`'s content to your error message to see if it really contains what you expect. Handling exceptions should also be done to **add details**.

Comment: Delphi gives: `'[{"name":"rot"},{"name":"gruen"},{"name":"Blau"}]'`
HTML gets:  `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]  `

Comment: As per [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-0.9.622#add_webmessagereceived) `arg.data` is not a text to begin with, but already an object. Don't try to parse: implicitly treating this as text/json is a prime mistake.

Comment: @AmigoJack That was ist. Thank you so much.
I am new to this forum. Hence my question: How do I write the solution without changing the problem.

Comment: Post the improved `try ... catch ...` code part as answer, then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AmigoJack

```
  try
  {
    step = 2;
    text = '<table border="1">\n';  // Linebreaks will help us when debugging
    for (let x in arg.data)
    {
      // Don't want to accidentally insert HTML where only text is supposed (XSS)
      text += '<tr><td>'
           + arg.data[x].name.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
           + '</td></tr>\n';
    }
    step = 3;
    text += '</table>';
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    // Even more details, like how far we came
    step = 'Fehler: ' + e.message
         + '\nStep: ' + step
         + '\nData: ' + arg.data
         + '\nText: ' + text;
  }
```

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks for the refinements. But can you still see the carryover from the original?
[w3.p2hp.com] https://w3.p2hp.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_table_dynamic

Comment: I don't understand the question. The linked code is also prone to XSS, is consistent with JS String literals but also not consistent with HTML attribute delimiters.

Comment: My goal was to execute an AJAX request, which is called in the standard examples with XMLHttpRequest, against a Delphi application. Will an outstanding person see the carryover from the example? But maybe I've already gone too far myself.